# Having problem to connect to my SQL database to add values in my table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, database-connection

Here is my code:

```
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('Database error:' . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, verified, token, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ssbss', $username, $email, $verified, $token, $password);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    //login user
} else {
    $errors['db_error'] = "Database error: Failed to register";
}
```

The output when I enter good inputs, it print in the error area:
Database error: Failed to register

Also, I defined the variables: DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME

the same as in my Xampp phpmyadmin settings.

If you need more info just tell me and i'll try my best give it to you.

Comment: what is the error message you get , paste the text

Comment: You can check the returned value after the execute :

Comment: here is the error message: 
Database error: Failed to register

Comment: For the "ssbss", it means that your verified data is BLOB type, are you sure ? (or you should use "sssss" ? just wonder

Comment: how can I verify because I did'nt and I want it to be a Boolean for my row type tinyint in my database table?

Comment: for boolean field, please try using integer instead of BLOB. (so should be ssiss). Please note that BOOL is different from BLOB

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer. That was actually the solution for my problem,